# Having trouble installing watir-webdriver because Ruby version is not >= 2.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I've recently installed ruby on my system. The first time I didn't specify a version, so I got ruby 1.9.3 (that's what comes up when I run `ruby -v`), but I installed ruby2.0 also, but when I run

```
sudo gem install watir-webdriver --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing watir-webdriver:
    selenium-webdriver requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? If so, you can try `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` to choose the default ruby version. Or just use rvm and forget the system ruby.

Comment: FWIW: link to https://rvm.io/

Comment: @orde, I installed rvm and ran `rvm use ruby 2.0` and I was prompted to install it. I installed it and tried `rvm use ruby 2.0` which produced `Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648`, and after trying `sudo gem install watir-webdriver --no-ri --no-rdoc` I get the same error as in the original post.

Comment: what @titusfortner said ;)

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your Operating system, but for Linux / Mac, you should use [RVM](https://rvm.io/), and for Windows I've had success with [URU](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru)

Comment: I installed rvm and ran `rvm use ruby 2.0` and I was prompted to install it. I installed it and tried `rvm use ruby 2.0` which produced `Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648`, and after trying `sudo gem install watir-webdriver --no-ri --no-rdoc` I get the same error as in the original post.

Comment: Don't sudo your gem installs.

Comment: :-D Whoops! Thank you.